# Annotation processor 'lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor' not found

Tags: playframework, lombok

I need to run on my computer project which was write using Play Framework with Lombok. My colleague is working on this project every day without problems, but when I clone repo from GitLab remote repository and write **activator compile** in command line i receive this error

```
[error] error: Annotation processor 'lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor' not found
[error] 1 error
[error] (domain/compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2015-01-15 13:39:38
```

Could You please help me with finding a solution to this problem ?

Thank you for Your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution..., it is not the best but it works. It looks like I have some problems on my Windows user profile, because when I switch To Another user profile everything works great.... So I switch to another profile and remove the old one....